# IO File Problem

Tags: .net, vb.net, io

I have this program:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        IO.File.Create("C:\text.txt")
        Shell("notepad ""C:\text.txt"" ")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

My question is: How to make my program not to use the newly created file 'text.txt'? Notepad fails to open it, it says (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `Close()` the `FileStream` returned by`Create()`:

```
IO.File.Create("C:\text.txt").Close()
```